# Configurable swatches - keep correct image proportions

Tags: magento-1.9, swatches

The images created for the configurable swatches are stretched to fit the square div and image proportions are ignored. Images that are rectangle shaped will end up being distorted.

This is what the image should look like (taken from the thumbs view in magento 1.8.1.0):

[image]

This is what it looks like for the actual swatch:

[image]

***[Moderator edit: adding relevant comment to body]***

There is a template located at catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable\swatches.phtml and the code responsible for the swatch images is as follows:

```
 <img src="<?php echo $_swatchUrl; ?>" alt="<?php echo $_option->label; ?>" width="<?php echo $_swatchInnerWidth ?>" height="<?php echo $_swatchInnerHeight ?>" />
```

Changing this will have no effect on the image proportions however.

Comment: PHP: when generating the pictures, ensure the correct width AND height are set. Moreover, add a style="width: ... ; height: ..." so the web browser processes the pictures faster.

Comment: I tried it via css but the generated images are already distorted so I need to change the php function itself. The magic should happen within app\code\core\Mage\ConfigurableSwatches\Helper\Swatchdimensios.php but I am afraid altering this file exceeds my skills...

Comment: You should configure a template file (.phtml) like so http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-change-products-images-dimensions.html

Comment: There is a template located at catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable\swatches.phtml and the code responsible for the swatch images is as follows:

`<img src="<?php echo $_swatchUrl; ?>" alt="<?php echo $_option->label; ?>" width="<?php echo $_swatchInnerWidth ?>" height="<?php echo $_swatchInnerHeight ?>" />`

Changing this will have no effect on the image proportions however.

Comment: Please post the generated HTML.

Comment: @loeffel please add your comment as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ran into this and perhaps someone has a better solution, but we extended 
the configurable swatches `productimage.php` helper with our own module. Perhaps `Magento intended everyone to create manual swatches` for every product. That tis time consuming and we have products that does not work well for. They uses the Varien Image model which allowed them access to caching, but does not have the convenient default settings of the MAGE catalog/image model. The nice part is those functions are available.

**If you don't know how to create a module would suggest making square images. "Do Not Edit The Core Files" Extend Them!**

We extended the

```
protected function _resizeSwatchImage($filename, $tag, $width, $height)
{
```

below

```
$processor = new Varien_Image($sourceFilePath);
```

we added

```
$processor->backgroundColor(array(255, 255, 255)); 
// Set background color to white
$processor->constrainOnly(TRUE); 
//Constrain to proportions
$processor->keepAspectRatio(TRUE); 
//keep existing aspect ratio
$processor->keepFrame(TRUE);
//Kinda what it says
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Swatches are designed to have a standard width and height among all Swatches in Magento, unfortunately.

Without overriding the way Magento works, your best bet would be to either make your swatch images the same aspect ratio that Magento expects (by default a square) or to change the default swatch dimensions (if you have a set ratio you plan to use throughout your store).

The swatch width and height are set in the Configurable Swatches section of the Catalog configuration.  Specifically, you'll find three sections: Swatch Dimensions on Product Detail Page, Swatch Dimensions in Product Listing, and Swatch Dimensions in Layered Navigation.

Magento automatically resizes the images to fit these dimensions before rendering them onto the page.

Comment: Shouldn't this be reported as a bug then? I use square images throughout my entire catalog and the dimensions are always correct. I don't understand why swatches should be calculated differently. Replacing thousand product images with square versions simply isn't an option.

Comment: @loeffel I don't think they're intended to be used the way you're using them.  I think their preliminary use case is for colours, sizes, etc.  You seem to be including a full product picture for the swatch.  Ideally you'd show something much more abstract and easier for the shopper to identify the difference.

Comment: Navarr, I understand your point. But the fact, that magento will include my product images as swatches if I name them accordinly, is kind of contradictory to what you are saying.
I have however accepted your reply, as I doubt we will find a true solution regarding this behavior.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @loeffel That's true and unfortunate.  It might be possible to write a patch for it, but I doubt Magento cares too much about the 1.x line when easy workarounds are available.